# User Preferences, Store in DB or cookies?

Tags: php, database, cookies

Evening all,

Not sure if this question is really acceptable criteria but ill try anyway.

I need to store user pref. on simple things like; Which order for blog posts to show, comments on and off, etc.

These could be stored via cookies, or possibly in the DB simply with a number variable. No 'personal' data will be stored just basic preferences which can be updated from the users settings page.

What would be the best way? Im more possibly leaning towards the DB way...

Thoughts?

Comment: I would imagine a DB would be better poised for this considering cookies can be deleted by the user. Passing these for a single session could be done with cookies (or php sessions).

Comment: If user does delete cookie, is it a case of "so what?" or is there a degree of pain involved?  If the former then use cookies.

Comment: Its not a big loss if they do, but i try to design websites with the feeling of using an application so i think a DB will best suit this and give consistency of their settings / statistical data for me. Just wanted to make sure using a DB for this sort of thing wasn't frowned upon as to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way ? It's depend of your criterias. Yours'll be different of mines.

DB storage is better if you need :

- Important control of the data (data type, possible values, other security rules...)
- Permanent storage (cookies are very volatile)
- Client usage statistical (or other functionality where the admin need access to these preferences)
- ...

The best advantage of cookies is, in my view, the very fast implementation (no configuration, no table to generate, very easy to use with recent framework).
The worst disadvantage is that cookies are only on 1 device.

So what are you criteria of what would be a good solution?

Comment: Well its just to make the User experience better and give them control of how they view blog items. So currently, you have to push a button to show comments. I want them to be able to change this in their settings so they can always have them on / off. And then also want to allow then to change the order they view the comments / the blog posts etc.

I guess an advantage of using a DB is a consistent settings page for them incase they do delete any cookies.

Comment: Furthermore for people who navigate on your website with 2 or more device (tablet, desktop, ...), cookies storage doesn't allow cross storage...

Comment: thats the decider for me. didnt think about that one. Db it is :)